# Comparing and highlighting differences between old and new excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro with limited programming background.  I have two excel files I'm trying to compare and find what has been changed from older iteration to the newer one.  Column A has a specific id number and everything in that row is information pertaining to that id number.  I would like the macro to find the matching id number and then compare the data in that row and highlight any changes that have been made in the newer iteration. the loop would have to go down each cell in column a of one file and compare it to the entire column in the other file each time.

If the id number isn't found then that id number needs to be highlighted as well. It also needs to check to see if the id numbers from the original file are still in the newer one, if not those need to be highlighted as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Spreadsheet Compare](http://www.thefoolonthehill.net/drupal/Spreadsheet%20Compare), a free tool for comparing Excel workbooks. It has lots of options, including "Database Style Compare", where you can highlight rows as you describe based on a column you choose as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

1.

Try PUP from J-Walk:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/pupv7/utilities

Compare Ranges: 
Lets you easily identify the differences between two worksheets or ranges.

2.

Check this comparison utility officially released by Microsoft, but for Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/basic-tasks-in-spreadsheet-compare-HA102834117.aspx

3.

If you import your 2 ranges into Access database, then you can use template queries from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ready-made software is better than making a macro.
It's very easy.

I use the following software.
This software compares two Excel workbooks, and highlight their differences.

[Excel Compare Tool - Excel Diff](http://www.suntrap-systems.com/ExcelDiff/)